# Reading JSON response from sever1 and returning the same JSON as response for server3

Tags: php, python, json, codeigniter

I have the following arrangement.

Server3 has a Codeigniter application runing on server3.S3 makes a call to s2 with some headers like this

```
$parse_auth = $this->parse->login($result->email, $this->input->post('password'));
```

now, on S2, I have a python script that makes a call an external Parse API, which returns JSON response; 
Here is the complete code:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import logging
import cgi
import urllib2
import json

PORT = 9500
headers = None
BASE_URL = 'https://api.parse.com'

class ServerHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

def do_GET(self):
    SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
    args = self.path
    parse_url = BASE_URL+args
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('Accept', self.headers.getheader('Accept')),('X-Parse-Application-Id', self.headers.getheader('X-Parse-Application-Id')),('X-Parse-Client-Version', self.headers.getheader('X-Parse-Client-Version')),('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', self.headers.getheader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key'))]
    response = opener.open(parse_url)
    print response.read()
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(json.dumps(response.read()))// I tried without json.dumps, didn't work

def do_POST(self):
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
        fp=self.rfile,
        headers=self.headers,
        environ={'REQUEST_METHOD':'POST',
                 'CONTENT_TYPE':self.headers['Content-Type'],
                 })

    SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = ServerHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

when I print response from S1 on s2, It appears JSON.

But on S3 when I print the array **$parse_auth** I get

```
-1
Bad Request
```

I want S3 to receive proper JSON response. How to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was mistakenly calling
SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)
in the first line of do_GET, which resulted in wrong response.

Answer (score 0):

Well to start you're always going to have to use either json.dumps() or jsonify() in order to format your outgoing JSON properly. But to your question, it looks like this should work, but on what route is your PHP server taking requests? It might have something to do with request headers.

Also, is there a reason you're using python urllib? These kinds of problems are exactly what the requests module was designed to prevent by having you not have to worry about things like request headers.

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Sending your request could be as simple as this.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json; charset=utf8'
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.text
u'{"type":"User"...'
>>> r.json()
{u'private_gists': 419, u'total_private_repos': 77, ...}
```